# Disable Cut, Copy, Paste and Paste Special in a specified sheet and in a specified column from outside sources

Tags: excel, vba

I need to disable Cut, Copy, Paste and Paste Special in a specified sheet and in a specified column from the outside sources.

I'm using the below code for disabling these features in the third column of a specified sheet. But the user is able to copy and use paste special to paste data.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'TARGET IS YOUR VALIDATION CELL
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 3

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Application.EnableAutoComplete = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(3)) Is Nothing
    End Select
End Sub
```

How do I restrict Cut, Copy, Paste, and Paste Special in the specified sheet and in the specified column?

Comment: You cannot prevent copy/paste properly. The only way is to lock the cells for writing. What is the purpose of doing this? You asked X but your actual problem is Y, please read [what is the x/y-problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and explain your actual issue.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, I understand that. But I'm using the above-mentioned code is used to disable just copy within the sheet. But now I would need to disable Cut, Copy, Paste & Paste Special in 2nd sheet and that too in B Column, from outside sources also. This is the actual problem. 

The purpose is actually, I'm using this code in time tracker, where the activity needs to be selected from the drop-down, instead, the user is copy-pasting in the cells from other sources. Please help!

Comment: You cannot prevent that someone is pasting into a cell if he copied from a source outside of Excel. If he can write to that cell he can also paste.